# Mosaic overlapping, irregular raster layers produces grid of NaN

Tags: qgis, saga, mosaic

I am trying to use the SAGA - Mosaic operator in QGIS 2.14.0 to mosaic two viewshed raster outputs I have. The viewsheds are irregularly shaped and overlap considerably, thus the need for the Mosaic operator; however, I keep receiving an output grid of NaN values.

Any ideas why this might be occurring?